# Ubuntu for Acer netbooks?

Tags: windows, wubi, ubuntu-netbook, acer, cpu

I want to install Ubuntu on my Acer netbook. But I've had problems with the new version. The problem is with the cpu or something like this. Is there an Ubuntu version for netbooks? What can I do? Because I have tried with an USB stick, the downloaded version for windows, but it's impossible. Thank you.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What's causing the problem?

Comment: although he does not state the problem cause directly, the CPU seems to be the main culprit.

Answer (score 1):

There *was* an Ubuntu version for netbooks, but Canonical stopped production at 10.10 Maverick Meerkat.

If you really want to install it, you can get it from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-netbook-i386.iso). However, the support for it ended on April 10, 2012, which means that if you install it, you will not receive updates or support for Canonical.

If you do not want to use Ubuntu Netbook Edition (a good idea; it is outdated and most of it's features have been merged with the main release), you can install the "Gnome" package from the Ubuntu Software Center (or run `sudo apt-get install gnome`), which will install Gnome Classic, which uses less resources than the Unity shell.

Another option for you would be to install [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) , an Ubuntu version with the lightweight window manager LXDE and lighter-weight alternatives to Ubuntu's stock software.

Comment: Later version of Ubuntu (desktop) are not any *less* suitable for netbooks than the old "Netbook Edition." The only reason there is no longer a separate Netbook Edition is that it has been merged into the desktop edition.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, I've successfully installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my netbook (Grundig) last year and then upgraded to 12.04 this April perfectly. Previously it was used by my daughter with Windows pre-installed, and she commented that it was a superb system upgrade :-)
Ubuntu is much more friendly towards (and compatible with) netbooks than Windows. 
Your problem is probably with the USB image. I think you should perhaps try another way for USB installation, e.g. http://liveusb.info to make a good working Ubuntu Live USB image.
I recommend that you boot your netbook from this USB and see if you I have a working Ubuntu Live system by going to desktop and trying it out first, and then rebooting to install this time before going to the Live session.
Don't worry, your Windows installation will work as before if you install Ubuntu in a second partition. You may also consider using a third partition for your data (e.g. in NTFS format) to use from both systems.
Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

I have an Acer Aspire One ZG5 that has 1.5gb RAM that I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 32bit. It is slow to open applications and does lag when streaming video, but has no major problems. I've been running Ubuntu on it for over a year and I am happy with it, just don't expect great speed. Something unique about this netbook keeps me using it. Even though it is the slowest piece of technology that I have.

Answer (score -1):

I've just updated my Acer aspire one to the latest version of ubuntu 12.10. I took the following route:

- Wiped the hard disk using dban via DVD (USB version wasn't working);
- Downloaded ubuntu 12.10 as iso file on windows PC;
- Used universal USB installer on PC to create installation files on a 4GB USB drive;
- Changed boot order of netbook to boot from USB key drive;
- Installed ubuntu via USB key;
- I initially had problems with wireless which are now resolved;

Seems so far to work but early days yat.